# Is a 32 bit integer on a 16 bit machine possible?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, embedded

Just wondering if it possible. If yes, are there other ways besides compiler emulation layer?

Thanks

Comment: Same way you can manipulate numbers bigger than you can hold in your head - one manageable piece at a time, with rules for how to combine the operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's processor-dependent. Some processors have special instructions to manipulate register pairs (e.g. the 8-bit AVR instruction set has instructions for 16-bit register pairs). On processors without such native support, the compiler usually emits instructions that work with pairs of registers at a time (this is what is usually done to support 64-bit numbers on 32-bit processors, for example).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. Look at the [Z80](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z80) from the 70s as an example of a 8-bit processor that can manipulate 16-bit values.

Make sure you know what "16-bit processor" means because I have found a lot of people have a misconception about it. Does it mean the opcode size, because some processors have variable width operations? Does it mean the addressing size? Does it mean the smallest/largest value it can natively manipulate?

And as far as at compile-time, sure. Check out [arbitrary large number libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) (aka "big nums").